# C# WebRequest POST Parameters are not coming through

Tags: c#, post, parameters, webclient

I'm trying to post to a webpage using WebClient in C#.
Somehow the parameters are not coming through.
The page itself is a php page.
I've tested the same page with a regular browser/html page and then it works, so I'm expecting that it is a client issue

Can anybody tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
        WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
        myClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        try
        {
            NameValueCollection keyvaluepairs = new NameValueCollection();
            keyvaluepairs.Add("request", "foo");
            byte[] responseArray = myClient.UploadValues("http://www.motio.com/test.php?id=7", "POST", keyvaluepairs);
            string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: You're ignoring any exceptions, so if something goes wrong you won't see it.

Comment: Install findler on your machine and see what is going on

Comment: You are correct. The actual code, however, will not do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm very sorry for taking up your time. After further investigation, it turned out that the url I used was using http and the server redirected me to http, losing the post variables.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing a GET instead of a POST just to make sure it is something wrong with the web request itself?

Comment: I did. I see the result of that test is still in the uri posted above;
http://www.motio.com/test.php?id=7
The get ('id') parameter was coming through.